# Reset Xfce4 Application Finder Size

Tags: xubuntu, xfce

On Xubuntu, when you press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> the Application Finder usually pops up as a small window in the middle of the screen.

I messed up something and now it spawns as a much larger window at the top half of the screen. How do you reset it back to the original disposition? There doesn't seem to be anything relevant under "Preferences".

[image: screenshot of the problem]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking under `~/.config/xfce4` I found `~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-appfinder.xml`

In there, there was a "property" XML node named "last" containing several other nodes, "window-height", "window-width" and "pane-position". I deleted the whole "last" XML node with a text editor, restarted the computer and now AppFinder spawns where it used to. Afterwards the AppFinder itself rewrote the configuration file with the default coordinates.

```
$ tail ~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-appfinder.xml 
      <property name="save" type="empty"/>
      <property name="command" type="empty"/>
    </property>
  </property>
  <property name="last" type="empty">
    <property name="window-height" type="int" value="400"/>
    <property name="window-width" type="int" value="400"/>
    <property name="pane-position" type="int" value="180"/>
  </property>
</channel>
```

Comment: Good answer +1.  However, a simple log out and log back in should be sufficient enough to reload the properties.

Comment: Did it not work simply resizing the window to what you prefer? I would expect the last window size and position is saved authomatically in that xml file.

Comment: @vanadium Yes, that's how it seems to work. However I wanted a clean reset to the defaults.

Comment: OK, then just deleting that entire file may have been an easier way to reset just everything to factory defaults.